# Does telegraf automatically attach timestamp when sending data to influxdb?

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I am using telegraf on several machines sending data to influxdb. However, I am not sure whether they attach the timestamp while sending. Also, it is difficult to dump the packets for the connection is https. These machines may have large time offsets so I prefer to let influxdb add the timestamp when the data reaches it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Telegraf automatically adds the current time to each data record it sends to telegraf.
When you have a look at the data sent (if telegraf's lineformat is used, which most output plugins do, including the default influxdb output plugin "outputs.influxdb"), it's the lengthy number at the end seperated by a space from the rest of the data, e.g."1601292600000000000".
That's nanoseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00 (also often referred as "Unix timestamp in nanoseconds").